# TeeChart X Axis Label Formatting

Tags: c++builder, vcl, teechart

I’ve got my TeeChart looking pretty good, the grid lines / ticks appear where I wish and so forth (the X Axis LabelStyle is set to talAuto). Now I need to format the X Axis labels so they display a time offset rather than the data point number.

I’ve changed the LabelStyle to talMark and am handling the chart’s OnGetAxisLabel.  The problem is that my event handler is called for every X Axis point rather than just the points which displayed labels when I had LabelStyle set to talAuto.

How can I set things up so my event handler is only called for the labels which were drawn when LabelStyle was talAuto?

I’m using C++ Builder XE3 and the version of TeeChart included with IDE.

UPDATE inspired by Yeray's comment:

With LabelStyle set to talAuto I always get ValueIndex of -1 passed to my event handler. In looking at the LabelText, I see values that I would have expected in ValueIndex, but I also get an equal number of incorrect values (ignoring non-X Axis values). For example...

My chart displays 5 X-Axis values: 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000. My event handler is called 10 times, in this order:

```
ValueIndex      LabelText
    -1              937.5
    -1                0
    -1          240,000
    -1              200
    -1          239,800
    -1            1,000
    -1              800
    -1              600
    -1              400
    -1              200
```

I have no idea where the first 5 values came from or why my event handler was called.

NOTE: I removed the C++ Builder tag because this question might be answered by anyone using TeeChart regardless of their language; the fact that I'm using BCB is not important to the question.

Comment: I added the vcl tag. the fact that you use BCB is partially relevant because there are different TeeChart versions that may behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

> I’ve changed the LabelStyle to talMark and am handling the chart’s
>   OnGetAxisLabel. The problem is that my event handler is called for
>   every X Axis point rather than just the points which displayed labels
>   when I had LabelStyle set to talAuto.

Right, using the `talMark` `LabelStyle`, the axis will draw as many labels as points in the series.
You can use the `talAuto` `LabelStyle` to get the number of labels you wish and you can still format the labels in the `OnGetAxisLabel` event.

---

UPDATE:

> When I use talAuto, ValueIndex is always -1 so I have no idea which
>   data point is associated with the event.

When `talAuto` is set and the series has labels, it behaves like `talText` and `talMark`: these strings are used in the bottom axis and the `ValueIndex` in `OnGetAxisLabel` event can be used.
When `talAuto` is set but the series has no label, it behaves like `talValue`: the bottom axis calculates the labels to show in function of the `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Increment`. The `ValueIndex` in `OnGetAxisLabel` event can't be used because the axis labels don't correspond to a series point.

I guess you don't have labels in your series. Otherwise, changing from `talAuto` to `talMark` shouldn't change anything.

So you have to decide between one or the other. Maybe you can use `talValue` (or `talAuto` without labels) to get the number of labels you wish, and extract the info you need from the string that is going to be drawn.

---

Alternatively, it could be easier to use `CustomLabels`. They will allow you to control both the positions and the text of the axis labels without needing any event. In example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries).FillSampleValues;

  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Clear;
  for i:=0 to Chart1[0].Count-1 do
    Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Add(Chart1[0].XValue[i], 'label ' + IntToStr(i));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yeray. When I use talAuto, ValueIndex is always -1 so I have no idea which data point is associated with the event.

Comment: I'd like to get the info from the string, but as I indicated in my update above (see the table in my post), my event handler is called 10 times for a chart that displays 5 labels; the first 5 calls pass strings with incorrect values. I have no way to know which calls contain legitimate value strings and which don't.

Comment: WRT Custom Labels, what is Chart1[0]? Since you’re using it to access XValue I guess it’s the TBarSeries you added above. But if that’s the case you’re labeling every point in the series; there can be tens of thousands (or more) in my application and many of them won’t be displayed (they’ll be to the left or to the right of the chart).  Making this work so that I exclude what’s not displayed and so that my labels are ‘nice’ – pleasingly displayed at proper intervals using pleasing values is not an easy task.

Comment: Since TeeChart will do all of that work for me and I can just extract the value from the text passed to my handler and massage it into a time offset, I’d much prefer to get my original code working.

Comment: Also, it looks like something’s wrong with TeeChart, or perhaps the way I’m configuring it. I don’t like these kinds of mysteries in my code. Have I narfed TeeChart? Do I have an overwrite or wild pointer that will bite me later? These are not issues which should be ignored lightly, so I’d like to get to the bottom of the erroneous labels.

Comment: The above was just a simple example of the CustomLabels usage. Of course if you have thousands of points you are not going to show all them in the screen at the same time (you can add the points from FirstVisibleIndex to LastVisibleIndex) or you probably wish to show a label each X points. And yes, `Chart1[0]` is the first series in the chart